# All possible path to reach particular node in directed graph

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm, directed-graph

I have a directed graph where paths are stored  in JSON array like. It is in the form of source and destination .

```
Var pathDirection =  [{"Source":2,"Destination":3},
{"Source":3,"Destination":4},
{"Source":5,"Destination":4},
{"Source":2,"Destination":5},
{"Source":4,"Destination":6}];
```

Using above it forms  graph like below structure .

[image]

My problem is I don’t know  the starting point and I have to find all possible  path to reach 6 from any node

Like for above graph different path to reach 6 is

**Output:**

```
    [4 ->6]
    [3->4 ->6]
    [5->4 ->6]
    [2->5->4 ->6]
    [2->3->4 ->6]
```

I have tried to write below algo  using backtracking which is working fine but looking for some best algo to find. Please suggest any other possible way to do same and how can i optimize below programe.

```
// BackTrack From End Node Destination 6

var getAllSource = function(destId){
    var sourceForsameDist = [];
    pathDirection.forEach(function(eachDirection){
      if(eachDirection.Destination == destId){
        sourceForsameDist.push(eachDirection.Source);
      }
  });
        return sourceForsameDist;
};

var diffPath = [];

var init = function(destination){
   var sourceId =  getAllSource(destination[destination.length - 1]);
    if(sourceId.length === 0){
      diffPath.push(destination);

    }
   for(var i=0;i<sourceId.length;i++){
     var copy  = destination.slice(0);
     copy.push(sourceId[i]);
     init(copy);
   }

};

init([6]);

console.log(diffPath);  // [[6,4,3,2],[6,4,5,2]]
```

Comment: Just search backwards (as if the edges were in the opposite direction) from your aim node, using DFS or BFS.

Comment: Can the graph contain circles? Should the result be an infite list then?

Comment: @Bergi What do want to say by graph contain circles? sorry for basic question .

Comment: Whether it's a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) or not. Your example is one, I wanted to know whether every possible input is one.

Comment: @Bergi it will never be  cyclic and does not loops back to same node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to do using backtracking which is working fine but looking for some best algo to find.

I'd call it [Depth-First-Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) instead of [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking), but yes the algorithm is fine.

However, I'd have some suggestions on the implementation:

- make `diffPath` a local variable and `return` it from the `init` function
- If you omit the `if(sourceId.length === 0)` condition then you will get the expected output, not only the the paths from the sources
- instead of looping through the whole `pathDirection`s in your `getAllSource` function, I'd use a lookup table that is filled before starting the traversal
- rename `init` to something more meaningful

Comment: Thanks my friend !! Your suggestions are awesome.